# Get facebook page feed pictures

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a news section on my website wich uses javascript API of facebook and a page token to display the facebook page feed.
I can get all fields correctly. So Text is ok and date time to. But the pictures won't work. I added the field links like this fields=message,link,created_time&format=json
But when i place the link url in img tags It will fail.
What is the best way to do this?

kind regards

Comment: Please show your code and explain exactly what isn't working

Answer (score 0):

A request like

```
/{page_id}/feed?fields=message,link,created_time,picture,attachments{media{image}}
```

should give you the image urls if present. Sample [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=poolcommunicatie%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dmessage%2Clink%2Ccreated_time%2Cpicture%2Cattachments%7Bmedia%7Bimage%7D%7D&version=v2.5) request returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "Ben je op zoek naar een nieuw logo? Wij maken ze ook in kleur..",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/DeBesteSocialMedia/photos/a.166454816883794.1073741829.123258531203423/416141615248445/?type=3",
      "created_time": "2015-08-22T14:50:51+0000",
      "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/11889585_416141615248445_3967918327489977693_n.jpg?oh=853f479d9a464379b583dc73fea6f61c&oe=5695B45A&__gda__=1451918152_9cc7a93bc0908d6f913b70d28a2041b8",
      "id": "236960899696782_957709484288583",
      "attachments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "media": {
              "image": {
                "height": 720,
                "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/11889585_416141615248445_3967918327489977693_n.jpg?oh=28134c850818297bbe8abc39207ec514&oe=56D18EA5",
                "width": 609
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great. and when I call api, it returned 25 lists as limit, could I get no limit? or how could we implement pagination when set limit per page?